# Can't install Package::Stash::XS

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to install the DateTime module with Perl 5.22 on Linux Mint 18. `sudo cpanm DateTime` fails with:

> Installing Package::Stash::XS failed. See [...] build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.

`--force` doesn't help, but using the plain old `cpan` revealed that

> usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE/perl.h:701:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory

Comment: `--force` almost never helps (bad advice, cpanm!). `--force` doesn't fix missing dependencies, it just installs the module if the tests fail; you generally don't want to install something that fails its own tests. Also, you don't need to switch to cpan just to find the exact error; the same output is in cpanm's build log, just like the error message told you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys/types.h` was brought in by installing `libc6-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

After installing that library, `DateTime` could be installed as well.